# Amazon Web Services - CreateDBSnapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am completely new to Amazon Web Services, however, I did get an account and I am able to browse our list of servers. I am trying to create a database backup programmatically using .NET. I have installed AWS for .NET and I have built and run the sample Empty console program.

I can see that I can create an instance of the RDS service with the following line:

```
AmazonRDS rds = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonRDSClient(RegionEndPoint.USEast1);
```

However, I notice that the `rds.CreateDBSnapshot();` needs a request object but I don't see anything like `CreateDBSnapshotRequest` in the reference .dll, can anyone help with a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said [CreateDBSnapshotRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_RDS_Model_CreateDBSnapshotRequest.htm) is the parameter you have to pass to this function.

CreateDBSnapshotRequest is defined in the **Amazon.RDS.Model** namespace within the AWSSDK.dll assembly (version 1.5.25.0)

Within CreateDBSnapshotRequest you must pass the the *DB Instance Identifier* (for example mydbinstance-1), that you defined when you invoked the [CreateDBInstance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_RDS_AmazonRDS_CreateDBInstance.htm) (or one of it's related methods) and the identifier for the snapshot you wish to generate (example: my-snapshot-id) for this DB Instance.

**edit / example**

Well there are a couple ways to achieve this, here's one example - hope it clears up your doubts

```
using Amazon.RDS;
using Amazon.RDS.Model;

...
...

//gets the credentials from the default configuration
AmazonRDS rdsClient = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonRDSClient(); 

CreateDBSnapshotRequest dbSnapshotRequest = new CreateDBSnapshotRequest();
dbSnapshotRequest.DBInstanceIdentifier = "my-oracle-instance";  
dbSnapshotRequest.DBSnapshotIdentifier = "daily-snapshot";

rdsClient.CreateDBSnapshot(dbSnapshotRequest);
```

Dont't forget that the DB Instance (in the example my-oracle-instance) must exist (duh :) and must be in the available state, like this:

[image: two DB Instances in the available state]

Comment: Do you have an example of the details and parameters you need to pass?  I have not found that anywhere....

Comment: Ok, that helped a ton!  So I have two more questions.  Is there a way to check to see if the instance exists and is in an available state?  Also is there a callback I can run on an async thread so I can get an update of when the backup is complete?

Comment: checkout http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_RDS_AmazonRDS_DescribeDBInstances.htm and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_RDS_AmazonRDS_BeginCreateDBSnapshot.htm :)

Comment: thanks for those links.  I have already checked out the documentation before starting this thread and there is very little information in there.  Right now I am stuck on the Callback.  I get an error: Unable to cast object of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.AsyncResult' to type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult' So I tried to change my code to use Amazon's AsyncResult: Amazon.Runtime.Internal.AsyncResult result = (Amazon.Runtime.Internal.AsyncResult)ar; but then then there is no AsyncDelegate property on the result object.